# Считать из файла и перевести из 16 в 10

Tags: c#

Необходимо считать значение `аа 37 00 00` в обратном порядке, чтобы получилось `00 00 37 аа`. После этого перевести из 16-го в 10-ое.

[image: картинка]

Comment: если необходимо, то нужно делать. да

Comment: Это хорошо, что у вас есть работа. Но в чем вопрос?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input = "aa 37 00 00";
    string[] arr = input.Split(' '); //Разбиваем строку на массив
    Array.Reverse(arr); //Реверсируем его

    string hex = string.Concat(arr); //Из реверстнутого массива делаем строку
    int output = Convert.ToInt32(hex, 16); //Конвертируем из 16-й в 10-ю СС
    Console.Write(output); //Выводим на экран

    Console.ReadLine(); //Delay
}
```

Comment: пойдет, спасибо